# How to print object of structure in bits representing its contents in C?

Tags: c, struct

I have the following c program

```
     struct in_addr {
            unsigned long s_addr;  // load with inet_aton()
        };

        struct sockaddr_in {
            short            a;  
            unsigned short   b;    
            struct in_addr   c;     
            char             d[8];  
        };

        int main(int argc, char** argv) {

            struct sockaddr_in *record1;
            record1 = (struct sockaddr_in*)malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in*));
            memset(record1, 0, 14);
            record1->a = 16;
            record1->b = 4;
            //strcpy(record1->sin_zero, "1");
            printf("Struct record1: %x", *record1);
        }
```

When i assign **record1->a = 16** alone, I get "**Struct record1: 10**"

When I assign **record1->a = 16** and **record1->b =4**  , I get "**Struct record1:40010**"   (I can find it is Little Endianness, but still ***my expected output is *04 10****(short takes two bytes each))

When I assign **record1->a=16;** **record1->b =4;** **record1->c.s_addr = 1UL;** **strcpy(record1->d, "1");**
    The output remains "**Struct record1: 40010**"(*Y is the assignment to long and char[] not reflected?*)

Can anyone explain this behavior. **I want to see how the contents of the structure are allocated in memory**. Are there any smarter ways to achieve this?

Comment: The smartest way to see the contents would be to use a debugger (if available).

Answer (score 3):

You're allocating space for the size of a pointer, not the size of a `struct sockaddr_in`. Thus you're overreaching your allocation boundaries and walking into undefined behaviour.

Try:

```
record1 = malloc(sizeof(*record));
```

Secondly, if you want to print a short, then print the short. I'm somewhat shocked your printf even *works* at all, considering you're sending a pointer-dereference (i.e. a struct-val) to be printed as a hex-int. If you're trying to print the *bytes* you need a enumeration algorthm to do so.

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)record1;
for (size_t i=0; i<sizeof(*record1); ++i)
    printf("%.2x ", p[i]);
```

is one such way you can do it. With the setup in your posted `main()` this produces:

```
10 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

which certainly makes sense. `a` is 16, and little-endian in a two-byte short is indeed `10 00`. Likewise `b` is 4, and again, a two-byte unsigned short, same little endian, is `04 00` .

Comment: @phonetagger heh. waiting for Huolon to spawn.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a `short`, which is generally 2 bytes long, and b is an `unsigned short`, also generally 2 bytes long.  A byte in `%x` (printf-style formatting) is two ASCII characters long, so 2 bytes would be 4 ASCII characters long (when printed with `%x`).  So both `a` and `b` together would be up to 8 ASCII characters long.  The way you're printing the contents of the structure isn't really correct, anyway... you should be printing each member:

```
    struct in_addr {
        unsigned long s_addr;  // load with inet_aton()
    };

    struct sockaddr_in {
        short            a;
        unsigned short   b;
        struct in_addr   c;
        char             d[8];
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        struct sockaddr_in *record1;
//      record1 = (struct sockaddr_in*)malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in*));
        record1 = (struct sockaddr_in*)malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        memset(record1, 0, 14);
        record1->a = 16;
        record1->b = 4;
        //strcpy(record1->sin_zero, "1");
        printf("Struct record1:\n");
        printf("    a = 0x%04x\n", record1->a);
        printf("    b = 0x%04x\n", record1->b);
        printf("    c.s_addr = 0x%08x\n", record1->c.s_addr);
        printf("    d = %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n",
               record1->d[0], record1->d[1], record1->d[2], record1->d[3],
               record1->d[4], record1->d[5], record1->d[6], record1->d[7]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at:

```
record1 = (struct sockaddr_in*)malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in*));
```

It probably does not do what you want. You probably intend to allocate memory to hold sockaddr_in  struct. That statement will allocate memory sized for a **pointer** to sockaddr_in.

The correct form would be (note that the * in the sizeof is gone)

```
record1 = (struct sockaddr_in*)malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

Now it allocates the correct amount of memory.

In the print line, you cannot directy print a struct, you need to do the hard work yourself, something along the lines of

```
printf("Struct record1: %x %x %x %s", record1->a, record1->b, record->c.saddr, record1->d);
```

To print the **pointer** to record1 use something like (note the * is gone - you want to print the pointer, not what it points to)

```
printf("Struct record1: %x", record1);
```

If you want to see the memory layout, you can use something like

```
char* address;
for (address = record1 ; address < (record1+sizeof(sockaddr_in)) ; address++)
{
    printf("Address: %x  Contents: %x\n", address, *address);
}
```

One more thing, prefer the use of sizeof() over "14":

```
memset(record1, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
```